# Understanding the formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, self-learning, markov-chains

> Let $P$ the transition probability matrix and $\mu$ the row vector of
>   initial distribution. $$P_\mu(X_n=j)=\sum_j\mu(i)p^n(i,j)=\mu p^n(j)$$

I don't want to make a proof of that, I want to understand it. Suppose I have a $3\times3$ transition probability matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}P_{00}&P_{01}&P_{02}\\P_{10}&P_{11}&P_{12}\\P_{20}&P_{21}&P_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$
and I have that $P(X_0=0)=p_0$, $P(X_0=1)=p_1$,$P(X_0=2)=p_2$ and I want to calulate $E[X_2]$

From what I know $$E[X_2]=0\cdot P(X_2=0)+1\cdot P(X_2=1)+2\cdot P(X_2=2)$$
but how I can calculate that probabilities?

For me it looks like $$P(X_2=0)=P(X_2=0|X_0=0)p_0+P(X_2=0|X_0=1)p_1+P(X_2=0|X_0=2)p_2$$
$$P(X_2=1)=P(X_2=1|X_2=0)p_0+P(X_2=1|X_0=1)p_1+P(X_2=1|X_0=2)p_2$$
$$P(X_2=2)=P(X_2=2|X_0=0)p_0+P(X_2=2|X_0=1)p_1+P(X_2=2|X_0=2)p_2$$
then

$$P(X_2=0)=P_{00}^2p_0+P_{10}^2p_1+P_{20}^2p_2$$
$$P(X_2=1)=P_{01}^2p_0+P_{11}^2p_1+P_{21}^2p_2$$
$$P(X_2=2)=P_{02}^2p_0+P_{12}^2p_1+P_{22}^2p_2$$

but that's not make sense for me, because
$$P(X_2=0|X_0=0)p_0+P(X_2=0|X_0=1)p_1+P(X_2=0|X_0=2)p_2$$
$$(*)P(X_2=0\cap X_0=0)+P(X_2=0\cap X_0=1)+P(X_2=0\cap X_0=2)\neq^? P(X_2=0)$$

perhaps this notation is confusing me, grateful for any explanation.

**EDIT:** Can someone explain to me in detail why $(*)$ is true?

Comment: $$P(X_2=0\cap X_0=0)+P(X_2=0\cap X_0=1)+P(X_2=0\cap X_0=2)=P(\cup_{i=0}^2\{X_2=0\cap X_0=i\})=P(\{X_2=0\}\cap \{\cup_{i=0}^2\{X_0=i\}\})=P\{X_2=0\}$$

Comment: @d.k.o. That's about disjoint union? I really don't understand the last equality

Comment: $\cup_{i=0}^2\{X_0=i\}$ is a certain event (occurs with probability 1).

Comment: @d.k.o. Do you have any reference where I can see it? I still do not understand well

Comment: Take events $A,B$ with $P\{B\}=1$. Then $P\{A\cup B\}=1$ and $$P\{A\cap B\}=P\{A\}+P\{B\}-P\{A\cup B\}=P\{A\}$$

Comment: @d.k.o. I understand this intuition just do not understand how you have applied it in the exercise